# Adding noise to a vector

Tags: image-processing, vector, matlab

I have a vector with float numbers such as:

```
Vect = [15.123, 21.345, 35.567, 45.362];
```

What I need is to apply a gaussian noise to only the numbers after the decimal point. for example, take the vector [123, 345, 567, 362], and then apply the noise on it. Therefore, replace the noisy vector in `Vect`.

I know that to add the gaussian noise, it can be performed as follows:

```
noisy_vector = imnoise(Vect, 'gaussian');
```

But I am interested to add the noise only to the numbers after the decimal point in Vect (automatically) in order to get the noisy `Vect`.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: I think by "comma" you mean "decimal point".

Comment: Exactly :) sorry, I edited my question

Comment: Just add Gaussian noise with an amplitude of `1` or `.1` ... or else you can extract the numbers like this `mod(Vect,1)` or maybe you prefer `mod(Vect,1)*100`. But basically, your question doesn't really mean anything since you haven't specified the parameters of the noise you want (i.e. mean and standard deviation)

Comment: When I didn't add the mean and Variance, so in this case by default the mean is equal to 0 and the variance to 0.01 :) , but can you write an answer containing how to add the noise on Vect but only on the numbers after the decimal point? I will appreciate your help very much

Comment: I don't understand your question. "Only on the numbers after the decimal point"? Which numbers?

Comment: Something like this, using Dan's comment - `noisy_vector = imnoise(mod(Vect,1), 'gaussian',0,0.01) + floor(Vect)`?

Comment: @Divakar please put your comment in an answer in order to accept it. Your answer is great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
%// Input
Vect = [15.123, 21.345, 35.567, 45.362]

%// Extract the decimal parts from the vector elements
decimal_part = Vect - floor(Vect)

%// Add gaussian noise to it with zero mean and 0.01 variance using imnoise
noisy_decimal_part = imnoise(decimal_part, 'gaussian',0,0.01)

%// Put the noisy part back to Vect to get the desired output
noisy_Vect =  noisy_decimal_part + floor(Vect)
```

**Output on code run**

```
Vect =
   15.1230   21.3450   35.5670   45.3620
decimal_part =
    0.1230    0.3450    0.5670    0.3620
noisy_decimal_part =
    0.2254    0.3554    0.4914    0.2918
noisy_Vect =
   15.2254   21.3554   35.4914   45.2918
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. Do you know what is the maximum value of the variance of Gaussian noise? By default is 0.01, but what is the maximum value? and for Salt & pepper what is the maximum?

Comment: @Christina Well I did a quick test with a very large rand Vect and increased the input variance gradually from 0.1 till 1E10 and measured the variance of the output. The convergence is reached with output variance at 0.25. So that might be it for the Gaussian one.

Comment: And what about Salt & pepper ?  does 0.35 is the maximum value ?

Comment: @Christina Well I could increase the input from `0` to `1` only as it was throwing error beyond `1`, and the output variance reached exactly `0.25` for this too. So I am guessing it's the same for S&P too. You might want to check with reliable sources though on these! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Vect = [15.123, 21.345, 35.567, 45.362];
dec=cellfun(@num2str,num2cell(Vect),'UniformOutput',false);
Vect_dec=regexp(dec,'\.','split');
mat=vertcat(Vect_dec{:});
dec_col=str2num(str2mat(mat(:,2)));
noisy_vector = imnoise(dec_col, 'gaussian');
```

This code would separate the digits after the decimal of each entry in the vector and then apply the gaussian noise to it. **Please note that this works only for the `vector` containing all float numbers**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `randn()` function to generate random numbers from a normal distribution of zero mean, with the standard deviation of 1.  Most of those would have an absolute value less than 1. If you are really worried about not changing the integer part of your elements, then you can divide the random numbers by 10.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a gaussian noise and have the figures before the decimal point stay the same all the time, because gaussian random variables can take values between -infinity and +infinity

If you want to randomize the figures after the decimal point and them only, you can do this

```
Vect = [15.123, 21.345, 35.567, 45.362]
VectInt=floor(Vect)
noise=rand(size(Vect))
NoisyVect=VectInt+noise
```